# "no such table: Games. Routine works on iPhone 5.1 simulator, but not on the iPhone device

Tags: iphone

I have an issue with loading my view (see below for code).  Basically, I am retrieving data from a table and displaying it on the iPhone screen.

The *iPhone 5.1 simulator* works, however, I get the message on device

> "Problem with prepare statement:  no such table: Games"

Can anyone give me a little direction?

Thanks in advance for your time and comments.

Here is the code:

```
-(NSMutableArray *) gameList{
 thegames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:5];
 @try {

    NSDate* date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMdd"];
    NSString* str1 = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    [toDaysDate setText:str1];

    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        NSString *docsDir;
        NSArray *dirPaths;

       dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *dbPath = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sportretortdatab2.sqlite"]];        

    BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
    if(!success)
    {
        NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
    }
    if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
    {
        NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    const char* GamesSQLString(NSString* str1);

    NSString* sql= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Games WHERE SeqNo= \"5\" AND GameDate < \"%@\"", str1];
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;

// THIS IS WERE I GET THE ERROR - THIS STATEMENT WORKS ON iPhone Simulator 5.1, NOT on iPhone device /////// 

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    {

         NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }else{
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
            Game * game = [[Game alloc] init];
            game.GameDate = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,1)];
            game.Completed = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,13)];
            if ([game.Completed isEqualToString:@"N"]) {
                NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", game.GameDate, @" - Open"];
                game.GameDate = strRR;}
            else {
                NSString * strRR = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", game.GameDate, @" - Completed"];
                game.GameDate = strRR;}
            [thegames addObject:game ];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
@finally {
    sqlite3_close(db);
    return thegames;
}
}
```

Comment: Where do you copy the db over to the documents directory? (also 2 tips: 1) don't use try catch to swallow errors, if you get an exception it means you did something pretty bad and you should probably just let it crash 2) don't make your properties start with capital letters, it violates platform conventions and makes it harder to read) EDIT: also I wonder if maybe you're not having issues with case sensitivity - is there a `games` table maybe? Just a thought :)

Comment: Carl - Thanks for your comments.  Since I wrote this issue I realized (dah). I am using the iPhone 5.1 Simulator, I recently upgraded my iPhone to iOS 6.1.  I have downloaded and using Xcode with the 6.1 Simulator.  The 6.1 Simulator is showing the list I am requesting, but I believe it's looking at a different copy of the db.  Basically, it's now not showing some information I added while in the iPhone 5.1 Simulator.  I am still getting the same error "no such table: Games" when I run on my iPhone. I believe the /documents/ folder on my simulator is copying the db.  I will check that.Thanks.